# Why do I get 0 as a result?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a complex program in C, but I get absurd results. I tracked the error in the definition of a constant. With this MWE I can reproduce the problem of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(){
      double Md=pow(10.,-9.);
     /*double Md= 0.000000001;*/
      printf("Md = %f\n",Md);
      return 0;
}
```

with both the definitions of `Md` I get `0` as a result. Why is it so?

Comment: Try it with `lf%` instead of `%f`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I still get 0.

Comment: You could try with the `%g` format specifier, and it'll tell you that `Md = 1e-09`

Comment: instead of `pow(10.,-9.)` use `1e-9`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for `%f` is six decimal places, hence 0 is output.

Be assured, `Md` will be non-zero in your debugger.

`printf("%.*lf\n", DBL_DIG, Md);` is one way round this: `DBL_DIG` is introduced via `<float.h>`, although you'd be advised to get used to *scientific notation*

```
printf("%e\n", Md);
```

which will permit printing of arbitrarily sized floating point values.

Comment: Using `%g` instead of `%f` also confirms that the value is non-zero (for me it shows `Md = 1e-09`).

Comment: Note that you need to `#include <float.h>` to get access to `DBL_DIG`.

Comment: `printf("%.*lf\n", DBL_DIG, Md);` is OK with `double Md=pow(10.,-9.);`, yet would still show zero with `double Md=pow(10.,-29.);`.  Code should use an exponential format `"%e"` or `"%g"` to check for non-zeroes.